# Redirecionar URL no IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web.config

Ao publicar no servidor (iis 7.5) a aplicação:

```
Eu tenho isso     => http://meuip:8086
Mas preciso disso => http://meuip:8086/portal
```

quando ou se criado o diretorio no iis com o nome "portal" e convertido para aplicativo é gerado um erro de url, pois no fonte não estão assim, exemplo de url no fonte:

```
em JS:
 var url = "/Portaria/Recado/Listar";
em C#:
 action="~/Gerenciamento/UsuarioExterno/Cadastro/0"
```

em C# o redirecionamento até funciona quando criado no iis um subdiretorio, mas o css e js não, pois no fonte o "/portal/" não existe.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não seria o caso de criar o /Portal como uma aplicação dentro do site :8086 ???

Comment: quando criado o /Portal dentro do NovoPortal e convertido em app eu tenho um erro nas URL's, pois meu css e script não possue o "/portal". Daí a url vem "http://meuip:8086/meucss" e esse caminho não existe. Existe agora "/portal"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Confirme se o módulo de redirecionamento está instalado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na versão em inglês o módulo se chama `Http Redirection`.

2) Abra o IIS, localize o módulo `HTTP Redirect` sob o site e diretório onde deseja criar o redirecionamento - no seu caso `/portal`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3) Informe a nova URL. Opcionalmente ajuste o código de estado para `308` - navegadores irão cachear a informação de redirecionamento após a primeira visita.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: opa... vou verificar....

Comment: a opção 308 não existe pra mim, só (302,301,307), vou tentar a 301 que é Permanent

Comment: @DanielleArrudatorres 301 e 308, se me lembro bem, são equivalentes para navegadores. Provavelmente irá funcionar para o seu caso.

Comment: não funcionou. Tens alguma noção do que pode ser?